# How do I write a prerequisite to loop through two lists of files together?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is an example illustrating the output I would like:

```
LIST1 := hello.o world.o
LIST2 := hello.c world.c

# Make the first object
# hello.o: hello.c
$(word 1, $(LIST1)): $(word 1, $(LIST2))
  cc -c $^ -o $@

# Make the second object
# world.o: world.c
$(word 2, $(LIST1)): $(word 2, $(LIST2))
  cc -c $^ -o $@
```

Is there a way to summarise the target: prerequisite text so that it loops through two entire lists?

I have tried using `foreach` functions with `word` functions but I don't get the output. I get non-numeric arguments to `word` and other invalid expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can do it, but it's *really* ugly (and would be hard to maintain),  I'm showing the answer, but  I am definitely not suggesting using it...  If you can use pattern rules as @MadScientist suggests, that would be best.   If not (say the names differ, you can do something like):

```
LIST1 := hello.o bob.o

hello.o : hello.c
bob.o : sally.c

$(LIST1):
    cc -c $< -o $@
```

Which allows you to specify custom prereqs for each target.   If you *really* need two lists, the technical answer to your question would be as follows:

```
LIST1 := hello.o bob.o
LIST2 := hello.c sally.c

all:

define recursive_def
$(firstword $(1)) : $(firstword $(2))
        cc -c $$^ -o $$@

$(if $(wordlist 2,3,$1),$(call recursive_def,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$1),$(wordlist 2,$(words $(2)),$(2))))
endef

$(info -v---v-)
$(info $(call recursive_def,$(LIST1),$(LIST2)))
$(info -^---^-)

$(eval $(call recursive_def,$(LIST1),$(LIST2)))
```

Comment: Ugly as it might be, the second one really works! I have several src/ subdirectories, and I'm compiling to a single build/ directory, I tried to describe the problem more generally so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Ah, I'm having a problem, the $^ and $@ aren't getting evaluated :/

Comment: If you're referencing variables inside of a define, then you need to escape the `$` to prevent the variable from being expanded before the variable is populated -- i.e., in your case you need to use  `$$^` and `$$@`.   Note that if you have a define that calls another define, then you need to use `$$$$` in the second define for the same reasons

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".  Why don't you just write a pattern rule?

```
all: $(LIST1)

%.o : %.c
        cc -c $^ -o $@
```

?  In fact you don't even need to write a pattern rule at all: make already has a default rule that can build object files from C source files.

**ETA**

If you have source files in different directories, you have two choices.  The best choice is to have one pattern rule and create all your objects in a subdirectory structure that mimics your source directories.  So, like this:

```
SRCS := foo.c bar/bar.c bar/biz/baz.c

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)

obj/%.o : %.c
         @mkdir -p $(@D)
         $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

If you really don't want to do that and you want to put all the object files into the same directory (a bad idea because if you have two source files with the same name in different source directories, your build will fail) you can use `VPATH`:

```
SRCS := foo.c bar/bar.c bar/biz/baz.c

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SRCS)))

all: $(OBJS)

obj/%.o : %.c
         @mkdir -p $(@D)
         $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: yes, that would work, except I have files under different directories, for example:

`build/hello.o: src/one/hello.c`, and `build/world.o: src/two/world.c`

Comment: This also doesn't work: `$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), %.o): %.c`

Comment: There's no difference between `$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR),%.o)` and just writing `$(OBJ_DIR)%.o` directly: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: If you have things in different directories your question should make that clear.  If you don't describe the actual complications in your question, you can't expect to get an answer that works there.

Comment: I think that it should read `$(SRCS:%.c=%.o)` in the assignment to `OBJS`, no? BTW: is this an argument against `VPATH`, as this problem (duplicate object file names) would always impend with its use?

Comment: Man I didn't have a great day yesterday for accuracy.  Will fix.  I wouldn't say this will always impede the use of VPATH, but in general it's something to consider.